# Migrating on an AWS Instance

Tags: migrations

I am given the task of migrating a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 9. I have been given a "mirror" site/exact copy that is being held on an AWS instance. Because the mirror site is up and running, I am assuming a LAMP stack has been installed. Could someone briefly outline how to install D9 onto this instance and migrate content over from D7 to D9? So far I have:

-updated the LAMP stack to make sure it's fully up to date.

-Downloaded D9 through Terminal in a separate folder away from the current D7 files.

-Create a new database in MariaDB.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal

Step 4 has me stuck; do I need to do this since the instanced is fully up and functioning as it's a mirror copy?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: That's a super broad request. I recommend you get a copy of the D7 site running on your local machine. Then install a fresh D9 (or D8) site. And then gamble around as much as you want on your local machine always having a backup of the D7 database at backhand.

Comment: Migrating a D7 to D9 is a very complex task that can't be answered here. You have to make a lot of changes and is heavy dependant of the modules and data you have.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question on the tutorial: if your Drupal 7 site is functioning, you don't need to do step 4 anymore. PHP is functioning.
You may proceed with step 5.

Indeed you will need to investigate what modules you use in the Drupal7 site and look if these have been ported to D9, or if there are interchangeable modules. Perhaps it's better to go for D8 first if you get stuck finding the appropriate modules and you're not able to make them yourself.